# Best option for photo/gallery handling?

Tags: images, gallery

Before I finally start blogging there's one last question that I need help with.
My blog will be photo-focused. We're talking about 70-80% of photos compared to 20-30% of text.
There might be some posts with up to 60 photos a ~200KB/file (~600px width).
I might also provide a clickable link to a larger version of the photo (using Lightbox or just leading to an external image host gallery).

My problem is that I don't yet quite fully understand what the best environment for a Wordpress blog is and thus I'm not sure if it's better to upload all the photos to my webhost, where also my Wordpress blog is hosted or if that's only slowing down the website and using an external image host, a CDN or whatever else is out there might be the better option?

What's my best bet?

As for image hosts, there are so many out there that it's difficult to choose from, so if that's a good way to do it, I'd be glad to hear some recommendations, especially those that will work well with Wordpress, of course.

Thanks a lot in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can keep your whole site together, i.e. texts and images, the main suggestion: just don't mix up large image/galleries with your text stream, this will indeed slow down your site loading. While most bloggers want display their pictures at any cost, most visitors just want read a specific text, then this  approach become annoying and frustrating to most visitors.

Create a gallery area for your site still displaying to visitors that you have a gallery area. There you can take some measures like generate thumbnails for your galleries, keep the images in CDN, load the big images files by AJAX etc.

That's it! (I miss Japan :,)

Answer (score 2):

> As for image hosts, there are so many out there that it's difficult to choose from, so if that's a good way to do it, I'd be glad to hear some recommendations, especially those that will work well with Wordpress, of course.

I wouldn't do that especially because if you change your mind later on to localize the galleries that are hosted elsewhere (a third-party photo/image-sharing site like Picasa, Flickr, SmugMug, etc), it'd be extremely difficult to do so.

---

> My problem is that I don't yet quite fully understand what the best
>   environment for a Wordpress blog is and thus I'm not sure if it's
>   better to upload all the photos to my webhost, where also my Wordpress
>   blog is hosted or if that's only slowing down the website and using an
>   external image host, a CDN or whatever else is out there might be the
>   better option?

[image: Jetpack Carousel]

<sub>**Click on the image to enlarge.**</sub>

Now that we have the beautiful (IMO) **[Jetpack](http://jetpack.me/) Carousel** for WordPress' native/standard gallery feature, I think you can go with it. You can find a [demo of the carousel](http://jetpack.me/2012/07/13/jetpack-1-5-with-carousel/) in action here.

Comment: Jetpack uses the native WordPress gallery, you won't need any other plugin. The images are attached to the post so you can use any other plugin someday by changing some code in theme.

Comment: @Diana hmm? You probably misunderstood my answer. The first part of the answer answers the quote. The second part is a suggestion as to what plugin the OP could use. Edited for clarity. :)

Comment: I'm also suggesting Jetpack. The gallery works with the WordPress native gallery so there's no need to use gallery plugins like NextGen.

Comment: @Diana Well, I did not suggest NextGen did I?

Comment: Noo, but must people do. NextGen is a huge project but I think WordPress can handle galleries very well.

Answer (score 1):

Your best solution is http://galleria.aino.se/  imho..
and you can use Flickr & Picasa if you want.